# Efficiently Remove Objects from Memory

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have the following code in main.lua
All I am trying to do is spawn rectangles, add them to physics so they can fall off the screen, remove the rectangles from memory once their y is greater than the screen height (means they are no more visible) and also remove those rectangles which are touched by the user.

Here is my code

```
local physics = require( "physics")
physics.start( )

--table to hold dynamically created rectangles
local rects={}
--used as index for table
local numRect=0

--event handler for rectangle touch
local function rectTouch(event)
    event.target:removeSelf( )
    event.target = nil
end

--function for spawning rectangles
local function spawnRect()
    numRect = numRect + 1
    rects[numRect] = display.newRect( display.contentWidth/2, 200, 200, 200)
    rects[numRect]:setFillColor( 1,1,1 )
    physics.addBody( rects[numRect], "dynamic",{density=1, friction=0,2, bounce=0  })
    rects[numRect]:addEventListener( "touch", rectTouch )
end

--function for removing rectangles which are no more visible
local function removeInactiveRects()
    for i = 1, #rects do
        if rects[i] ~= nil  then
            if rects[i].y > display.contentHeight + 100 then
                rects[i]:removeSelf( )
                rects[i] = nil
            end
        end

    end
end



timer.performWithDelay( 1000, spawnRect, -1 )
timer.performWithDelay( 2000, removeInactiveRects,-1 )
```

I get an error removeInactiveRects function stating that attempt to compare number with nil, I guess the statement responsible for this is `rects[i] ~= nil` but I don't know why. Additionally is it the right way to remove objects from memory?

Comment: `5 ~= nil` is a legal statement. That error is likely coming from the `rects[i].y > display.contentHeight + 100` comparison. Which means your `rects[i]` object doesn't have a `y` value at that point.

Comment: Yes .. I commented that line and seems like it is `rects[i].y > display.contentHeight + 100` that is causing problem. But I don't understand why since in the rectTouch() I am removing the object and making it nil, and the condition `if rects[i] ~= nil  then` should not allow it to reach `if rects[i].y > display.contentHeight + 100 then` if it is nil

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the touch `rectTouch` function, you need to remove not only the rectangle, also the reference you have in your `rects[]` table. You can create the rectangles with an id value, so you will be able to identify them in the event function and delete them.

```
--event handler for rectangle touch
local function rectTouch(event)
    local i = event.target.id
    event.target:removeSelf( )
    event.target = nil
    rects[i] = nil
end

--function for spawning rectangles
local function spawnRect()
    numRect = numRect + 1
    rects[numRect] = display.newRect( display.contentWidth/2, 200, 200, 200)
    rects[numRect]:setFillColor( 1,1,1 )
    rects[numRect].id = numRect
    physics.addBody( rects[numRect], "dynamic",{density=1, friction=0,2, bounce=0  })
    rects[numRect]:addEventListener( "touch", rectTouch )
end
```

I'm new also at Corona, so I'm not sure but maybe you could create some "ground object" at bottom+500 and detect the collision to remove the rectangle.
Look at [collision detection guide](http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/physics/collisionDetection/index.html)

Comment: In the real scenario which I am facing the issue is little different since I need to use the removeInactiveRects() as the rectangles are moved using transition.to() and not gravity. Detecting the collision of objects in transition with other object(border) has some issues.

Comment: Ok, but you still need to remove the rectangles you touch in your rectTouch() event, and use the onComplete event from transition.to() function to remove the others.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the statement `event.target = nil` does not set the corresponding `rects[i]` to nil also, it only converts the target from a display object back to a regular table. So after this statement, `rects[i]` for the `i` that corresponds to the target touched contains a regular table object, not nil, and this table object does not have a y field. Whenever you `removeSelf` on a display object, ensure you remove references from other objects such as tables like `rects`.

Also, regarding the removal once the object goes below a certain height, there are several ways to do this:

1. One is to make a transparent geometry (such as a line) that is a physics body with "isSensor" = true. In the collision handler, you must use timer.performWithDelay(function () event.target:removeSelf() end) since you can't immediately remove objects that are part of a collision event.
2. Another method is to use `PhysicsContact:isEnabled()` and in the collision handler, disable collision and schedule the object for removal.
3. Yet another method is to use the `enterFrame` on Runtime object and in its handler, check for any objects that have y > yMax. Those objects can be removed immediately.
4. Finally, the technique you have used of checking every 2 seconds works too.

But #4 technique loops over all "alive" boxes every 2 seconds, whereas the physics-based techniques (#1 and #2) only use compute cycles for those boxes that should be removed. OTOH, collision detection is itself somewhat demanding, but in 2D maybe not so much. The `enterFrame` approach (#3) is perhaps a bit of overkill because it is called at every frame (30 times/sec), whereas you just want to remove the object to free the physics from evolving objects that will never again be visible, but it doesn't matter if this cleanup occurs right as the object passes threshold, or a second later.

This is all explained in the collision docs of Corona.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
if rects[i] and rects[i].y > display.contentHeight + 100 then
```

It happens because some rects are removed, so their index in table is empty. If it's empty then it's obvious that it cannot have `.y` parameter.

You may avoid it also by inserting objects just like that:

```
local localRect = display.newRect( display.contentWidth/2, 200, 200, 200)
rects:insert(localRect)
```

And instead of using

```
if rects[i] ~= nil then
```

use

```
if rects[i] then
```

which mean "if there is any object (not "nil" and not "false" value) in rects[i]"